# scoping/non-standard evaluation issue in `glm()`'s formula in a function in R

Tags: r, function, scope, glm, evaluation

I have a function that computes a table and a model (and more...):

```
fun <- function(x, y, formula = y ~ x, data = NULL) {
  out <- list()
  out$tab <- table(x, y)
  out$mod <- glm(formula = formula,
                 family = binomial,
                 data = data)
  out
```

}

In the formula, I need to use `x` and `y` as provided in the function call (e.g. `x = DF1$x` and `y = DF1$y`) and variables from another data frame (e.g. `a` and `b` from `DF2`). It fails with my naive function:

```
fun(x = DF1$x,
    y = DF1$y,
    formula = y ~ x + a + b,
    data = DF2)
# Error in eval(predvars, data, env) : object 'y' not found
```

How can I make `glm()` search `x` and `y` from the function environment? I guess this issue is related to non-standard evaluation and/or scoping, but I have no idea how to fix it.

Data for the example:

```
smp <- function(x = c(TRUE, FALSE),
                size = 1e2) {
  sample(x = x,
         size = size,
         replace = TRUE)
  }

DF1 <- data.frame(x = smp(),
                  y = smp())

DF2 <- data.frame(a = smp(x = LETTERS),
                  b = smp(x = LETTERS))
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Why not just add `x` and `y` into `data` in the function?

```
fun <- function(x, y, formula = y ~ x, data = NULL) {
  if(length(x) != length(y) | 
     length(x) != nrow(data) | 
     length(y) != nrow(data))stop("x, y and data need to be the same length.\n")
  data$x <- x
  data$y <- y
  out <- list()
  out$tab <- table(x, y)
  out$mod <- glm(formula = formula,
                 family = binomial,
                 data = data)
  out
}

fun(x = DF1$x,
    y = DF1$y,
    formula = y ~ x + a + b,
    data = DF2)
# $tab
# y
# x       FALSE TRUE
# FALSE    27   29
# TRUE     21   23
# 
# $mod
# Call:  glm(formula = formula, family = binomial, data = data)
# 
# Coefficients:
#   (Intercept)        xTRUE           aB           aC           aD           aE           aF           aG           aH           aI           aJ  
# 3.2761      -1.8197       0.3409     -93.9103      -2.0697      20.6813     -41.5963      -1.1078      18.5921      -1.0857     -36.5442  
# aK           aL           aM           aN           aO           aP           aQ           aR           aS           aT           aU  
# -0.5730     -92.5513      -3.0672      22.8989     -53.6200      -0.9450       0.4626      -3.0672       0.3570     -22.8857       1.8867  
# aV           aW           aX           aY           aZ           bB           bC           bD           bE           bF           bG  
# 2.5307      19.5447     -90.5693    -134.0656      -2.5943      -1.2333      20.7726     110.6790      17.1022      -0.5279      -1.2537  
# bH           bI           bJ           bK           bL           bM           bN           bO           bP           bQ           bR  
# -21.7750     114.0199      20.3766     -42.5031      41.1757     -24.3553      -2.0310     -25.9223      -2.9145      51.2537      70.2707  
# bS           bT           bU           bV           bW           bX           bY           bZ  
# -4.7728      -3.7300      -2.0333      -0.3906      -0.5717      -4.0728       0.8155      -4.4021  
# 
# Degrees of Freedom: 99 Total (i.e. Null);  48 Residual
# Null Deviance:        138.5 
# Residual Deviance: 57.73  AIC: 161.7
# 
# Warning message:
#   glm.fit: fitted probabilities numerically 0 or 1 occurred 
#
```

Comment: That's the suggestion I was going to make too.  The only reason you wouldn't want to do this is if a variable named `x` could already exist in the formula environment or in the dataframe and you wanted it to have priority over the one that's an argument to the function.  But I don't think the OP wants that.

Comment: Agreed, but it is difficult to imagine a situation consistent with the OP's post where there would be a variable `x` in `data` that you would want to take precedence in the model.  In fact, I think in this particular situation overwriting an existing `x` in the `data` would be a feature rather than a flaw.  In general, though, I think your caution about this is quite reasonable.

Comment: Simple and effective! Thank you! It also works with `fun(DF1$x, DF1$y)` what I didn't expect since `data = NULL`.

Comment: @user2554330 @DaveArmstrong The solution works perfectly. However, could you please explain why I got the error in the first place? From `glm` documentation, data is "an optional data frame, list or environment (or object coercible by `as.data.frame` to a data frame) containing the variables in the model. *If not found in `data`, the variables are taken from `environment(formula)`, typically the environment from which `glm` is called.*" (emphasis mine) Therefore, why `x` and `y` are not taken from the function environment and `a` and `b` from `data`?

Comment: @user2554330 @DaveArmstrong To avoid potential issues if there is already variables named `x` and `y` in `data`, I added `stopifnot(! names(x = data) %in% c("x", "y"))`.

Answer (score 2):

@DaveArmstrong's answer that was already accepted is correct.  This answer explains why there was an error in the original version of the code.

@Thomas quoted the docs in a comment saying

> If not found in data, the variables are taken from environment(formula), typically the environment from which glm is called.

The word "typically" is key here.  The exact rule is that the environment attached to the formula is the one where the formula expression is first evaluated, because  `~` is actually a function.  It attaches the evaluation environment to the formula object, and that's the one that stays with it as you pass the object around.

If you run `glm(y ~ x)`, the formula is evaluated wherever you call that, so that's the "typical" case.

In your example, you created the formula object when you called

```
fun(x = DF1$x,
y = DF1$y,
formula = y ~ x + a + b,
data = DF2)
```

That means the global environment (where you made this call) is attached to the formula, and there's no `y` there, so you got the error.

If you had used the default `formula = y ~ x` by calling

```
fun(x = DF1$x,
y = DF1$y,
data = DF2)
```

with no `formula` argument, it would work, because default arguments are evaluated in the evaluation frame of the function that uses them.  Since `fun()` has local variables `x` and `y` created by the arguments, that would be fine.

You also asked why `data = NULL` would work in @DaveArmstrong's function.  He added `x` and `y` to it using

```
data$x <- x
data$y <- y
```

If you start with `data = NULL`, the first line changes it to a list containing `x` and the second line adds a `y` component, so you end up with a list containing `x` and `y` and that's fine for `data` in `glm()`.

Comment: Thank you very much for clarifying these points! I thought that the promise were evaluated only when needed (lazy eval). Does it not apply to formulas?